VS Code Git Detached state recovery
In MS VS Code 2022 the local Git has a Detached state. I did not know it was there and just kept working and making commits. Now there are 33 commits on the Detached in addition to all the commits on the original master.

Is it possible to get rid of this Detached state and instead bring all its commits back as though they had been made on master?
(I’ve no idea how the system got into the Detached state)
TY!

Hi @matt, TY for the speedy reply. The pic in the post has been changed to show all of the Detached section and the top part of the Master/Local History section. Do you still think the
git switch master; git reset --hard dd93d8ae
will bring all the Detached commits into the Master?

See my updated answer! Thanks for posting the revision.

Just reset master (hard) to the most recent detached commit.
git switch master
git reset --hard 948348b6 


I’ve no idea how the system got into the Detached state

Because you checked out a commit by its number (SHA) rather than its name (branch).

I just remembered that this project was transferred, the entire VS Code project structure including the .git folder , from one PC to another about the time the Detach seems to have happened. Maybe something about that process was done incorrectly?

I doubt that that's relevant. Copying an entire folder including its .git folder leaves the .git folder, and hence the HEAD (which is what got detached), intact.

Matt, your suggestion worked great. The Detached commits were folded back into the Master. For the help and attention, TY!
